# Sent Bitcoin to wrong email address on Coinbase.com

Tags: transactions, address, coinbase.com

I sent some BTC on coinbase to another one of my own email addresses. But I later realized I don't have a coinbase account with this email. The status of the transaction says complete.
Are they gone? Probably.
Or can I create a coinbase account with that email?

Comment: I would suggest trying to create an account with that email and see what happens